# How to sort strings inside an array by first letter in C

Tags: c

I'm looking to sort a recipe list. The recipe list is an array that contains recipe names as well as their ingredients, recipe names begin with 0 and ingredients begin with 1. I want to print out the available recipes in a list, but I'm getting a segmentation fault, is this a correct way to sort the list? Additionally, is it possible to print the item in the list without the 0 in front of it? 
Here is the code for the printing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "rawRecipes.h"
#include <string.h> 

void listRecipes(void){
int n = sizeof(rawRecipes); 
int i,j;
//temp place for putting string
char temp[30];   
  //iterate through recipe list array
  for (i=0; i<sizeof(rawRecipes); i++){
    //copies each item in recipe list array to temp
    strcpy(rawRecipes[i], temp);
    for (j=0; j<30; j++){
      if (temp[j] == 0){
        break; 
        printf("%s", rawRecipes[i]); 
      }
    } 
  }
}

int main(void) {
  listRecipes(); 
  return 0;
}
```

and here is the code for the list used in the header file:

```
char *rawRecipes[]={"0Broccoli Coleslaw","1olive oil","1white vinegar","1broccoli","0Creamy Broccoli Salad","1broccoli","1white sugar","1red onion","1white wine vinegar","0Minnesota Broccoli Salad","1eggs","1broccoli","1red onion",""};
```

Expected output would look something like: 
Broccoli Coleslaw \n Creamy Broccoli Salad \n Minnesota Broccoli Salad

***edit***
I've changed the code and it seems to be printing out the correct items, but multiple times, how do I alter the code so it only prints once?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "rawRecipes.h"
#include <string.h> 

void listRecipes(void){
int n = sizeof(rawRecipes); 
int i,j;
//temp place for putting string
char temp[30];   
  //iterate through recipe list array
  for (i=0; i<14; i++){
    //copies each item in recipe list array to temp
    strcpy(temp, rawRecipes[i]);
    for (j=0; j<30; j++){
      if (temp[j] == '1'){
        break; 
      }
      printf("%s\n", rawRecipes[i]); 
    } 
    //printf("%s", rawRecipes[i]); 
  }
}

int main(void) {
  listRecipes(); 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: what's `rawRecipes`? The arguments in `strcpy` are backwards, the destination comes first, source is second.

Comment: `sizeof(rawRecipes)` returns the size of the array *in bytes*, not the number of elements.

Comment: rawRecipes is the header file and recipe list

Comment: You need to compare the first character with a `char`, not a number: `if (temp[j] == '0')`

Comment: Why do you think you need to copy into `temp` in the first place? Just use `rawRecipes[i][0]`

Comment: Also note that `strcpy` does an actual copy to the destination, which first of all requires that the destination size is large enough to fit all characters of the source (including the string null.terminator) which some of your strings aren't. And secondly it requires that the destination actually can be written to, which a string literal *can't* be. Literal strings in C are arrays of non-modifiable characters, they are in effect read-only.

Comment: I meant the code definition of `rawRecipes`. As pointed out, `sizeof(rawRecipes)` probably isn't doing what you think it is.

Comment: To solve your problem, compare the strings (using their first character if that's what you want) and then swap the *pointers* instead of copying the strings themselves. I also recommend that you learn to use the standard [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) function instead of inventing your own sorting.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The intent is to copy to `temp`, not the string literals, they got the argument order backwards.

Comment: You can print without the first character with `printf("%s", &rawRecipes[i][1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have the arguments to `strcpy()` in the wrong order. But there's no need to make a copy, you can just use `rawRecipes[i]` directly.
2. `sizeof(rawRecipes)` is the number of bytes in the array, not the number of elements. You need to divide by the size of each element to get the number of elements.
3. There's no need for the inner loop. If you want to check the first character, just use `[0]`.
4. You need to compare with a the character `'0'`, not the number `0`'.
5. You can skip the `0` by printing starting at the address of `rawRecipes[i][1]`.

```
void listRecipes(void){
    int n = sizeof(rawRecipes)/sizeof(rawRecipes[0]); 
    int recipe_num = 0;
    for (int i= 0; i<n; i++){
        if (rawRecipes[i][0] == '0') {
            printf("Recipe #%d: %s\n", ++recipe_num, &rawRecipes[i][1]); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I just had one more question, if I wanted to print "Recipe #%d" in front of the recipe each time, how would I implement a loop for this? I've tried using a for loop (int j=0; j<=3; j++) but I can't seem to find the correct placement for it. So it should print Recipe #1 Broccoli Coleslaw \n Recipe #2 Creamy Broccoli Salad and so on

Comment: You don't need a loop for it. Just increment a variable every time you print the recipe name.

Comment: I've added it to the answer.